# Can I get IPTC and EXIF data from an image using imageMagick?

Tags: php, linux, image, imagemagick

I have tried:

```
identify -format %[exif:*] filename.jpg
```

Which returns nothing.

```
identify -verbose filename.jpg
```

Doesn't give me the data I want.

I am currently running:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.0.7 07/25/08 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2004 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

Should I be able to get this data with ImageMagick?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. identify will return exif data, but depending on how you make the call, the arg `%[exif:*]` might need to be quoted, e.g. from bash `identify -format '%[exif:*]' filename.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try

**[`exif-read-data`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php)**
It reads the EXIF headers from a JPEG or TIFF image file. This way you can read meta data generated by digital cameras.

It requires that PHP was compiled with --enable-exif flag, but most installations are.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
convert filename.jpg filename.exif

convert filename.jpg filename.iptc
```

Comment: I get the following: convert: no APP1 data is available `laker.exif'
I'm pretty sure the data should be there. Anything I might be missing?

Comment: Nope.  It's either not there or not recognized.  If you want to check, `vim laker.jpg` and `/Exif`.